# What is the URI format to create a Google Site with custom URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sites

Using python google appengine:

```
entry = client.create_site(orgName,
    description=orgDescription, 
    source_site='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/org' 
    uri='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/MyCustomURL')
```

I get "Invalid URI" for the uri=

Am I using an invalid format for the URI? uri='MyCustomUrl' does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in  your arguments list, though I don't know that this would fix the error you're seeing.  Can you copy/paste the actual error?

```
entry = client.create_site(orgName, description=orgDescription,
            source_site='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/org',  # this comma right here
            uri='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/MyCustomURL')
```